# Undefined method `mime_type` in Mailer Preview when using Attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types, actionmailer, email-attachments

I've created a mailer in my Rails 4 application, which works perfectly well when there are no attachments to the emails. However, when I add a pdf attachment to the emails, I get the following error when I try to preview the email at .../rails/mailers/donor_mailer/thankyou_mail_preview

```
NoMethodError in Rails::Mailers#preview

Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/mailers/email.html.erb where line #95 raised:

<iframe seamless name="messageBody" src="?part=<%= Rack::Utils.escape(@part.mime_type) %>"></iframe>
```

However, I don't get this error, or any issues at all actually, when sending the emails themselves, only with the preview. Has any one else experienced this, and know how to fix this / knows the direction I should be heading in. Could this cause any further issues down the line with my emails, or is it just a problem with the preview feature?

My Mailer is as follows:

```
class DonorMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "user@gmail.com"

  def thankyou_email(computer)
    @computer  = computer
    @donor = computer.donor

    attachments["some.pdf"] = File.read("path/to/pdf/some.pdf")
    mail(to: @donor.donor_email, subject: "Thank you")
  end

end
```

and template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>

  <body>

    <p>Email content here</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding :pdf to my MIME types to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: The mail gem, though I believe its included by default in Rails 4?

Comment: I think https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14435 will help you

Comment: Thanks Panda, this seems to address my issues exactly. From the references at the bottom of the post it seems that a commit was made to fix this issue 29 days ago. I'm currently running my app on Rails 4.0, so it seems that my solution will be to update to the newest version of rails.